# Blank white window while calling aura component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, aura-handler

Hello everyone
I created my aura component and added it like a button.
First I created an action in (Buttons, Links and Actions) section on object and then added it in (page layouts) ->(Salesforce Mobile and Lightning Experience Actions).
But when I click button it open empty window. I don't need a window at all. All functionality of my aura is call a method while initialization with

`<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>`

in aura component

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickAction"
                controller="ComponentController">
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
</aura:component>
```

this is code ComponentController.js

```
({

    doInit: function (cmp, event, helper){
        cmp.set('v.showSpinner',true);
        helper.isUpdatableRecord(cmp, event);
    },
    
});
```

I don't show code of helper because it isn't need, in it is only work with fields.
There is the picture below, where you can see the empty win and button "cancel"(i have no it in my component for example...).
I hope I describe the problem clear, thanks for your attention
[image: empty window]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [force:closeQuickAction](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:closeQuickAction/documentation) after doing your work to close the modal. It will still briefly appear, but then disappear afterwards. You might want to just add a [lightning:spinner](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:spinner/example) while your code is working so the users understand something is happening.

Comment: it worked for me, but it appears for some seconds. I wanted to hide it absolutely. My colleague advised to move code logic to lwc.